# Tabs on website opt-in form jumps to the opt-in form at the top of the page

Tags: wordpress, forms, input, tabs

So I'm stumped.

When I type in any of the boxes (the opt-in box fields - name and email) and hit Tab, I'm not brought to the logical next input box. See (http://juliehoughton.com/whatprocrastinationtellsyou/) so you can understand what I mean.

Is there something I can do to make this make sense? :)

I appreciate your time and help so much - thank you!

Liz

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the tabindex correctly :)

Example: `<input type="text" id="name" tabindex="1"><input type="text" id="email" tabindex="2">`

The problem is the top newsletter sign up and the bottom one have the same values (500 and 501). So you need to make sure the bottom ones are different (or set the top ones to a lower value). You should also adjust the submit button (set to 502).